# Javascript: Confuse about Object.defineProperties function

Tags: javascript, object

This is how I using `Object.defineProperties` to generate an objct:

```
var obj = {
    t3: 3,
    t1: Object.defineProperties({}, {
        getT3: {
            value: function () {
                console.log(this.t3);
            }
        },
        t2: {
            value: this.t3
        },
        t3: {
            value: 4
        }
    })
}
```

Now I want to print the `obj.t1.t2` value: `console.log(obj.t1.t2)`, but the return result is `undefined`

But I can using the `obj.t1.getT3()` method to obtain the `obj.t1.t3`'s value;

Why the `t3` assignment to `t2` doesn't work in `Object.defineProperties`?

DEMO is here: http://jsfiddle.net/HrLLQ/

Comment: The problem is actually not related to `Object.defineProperties`, but how `this` works in an object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is about the `this` element.

When you call `.defineProperties()`, the `this` element does not refer to the object you are in, or it's parent or wathever, but it refers to the `this` element of the function `defineProperties`, which is actually `window`.

Here is an example:

```
var foo = { bar: 10, b: { c: this, d: this.bar } }
console.log(foo.b.d); // logs undefinded, because the window object has no attribute .bar
console.log(foo.b.c); // logs the window object

function x() { y = this }
x();
console.log(y); // also logs the window object
```

To make it work you have to define the `.t2` property as a function like:

```
function() { return this.t3 }
```

So once the object has been created its `this` element will be `obj`, and `obj.t1.t2()` will return `obj.t3` (which is actually 3).

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot access `this` as above. Just define `t2` as a function and it should work

```
var obj = {
    t3: 3,
    t1: Object.defineProperties({}, {
        getT3: {
            value: function () {
                console.log(this.t3);
            }
        },
        t2: {
            value: function(){
                return this.t3;
            }
        },
        t3: {
            value: 4
        }
    })
}

console.log(obj.t1.t2());
obj.t1.getT3();
```